# Store values in MySQL in a particular way

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Excuse me for the title, but I just do not know if this particullary has some name I could have used, just let me know or edit the title with whatever is better.

Now, the question: I have two MySQL tables, one contains a list of items, each item has a unique ID and a title stored. The other table is a list of users. Both tables get more values every day (more users register and more items are added). I would like to save which items each user has already seen, I just need to know if he has or he has not seen a particular item. So, how should I store something like this, what would be the best way? I only thought about having a column on my users table with a string containing coma-separated IDs of the items. But ideally I would need a way that would allow me to do the next things:

- Get a list of all the users that checked an item.
- Get a list of all the items checked by some user.
- Get a list of all the items that an user has not checked.
- Get a list of the items that not any user has checked.
- Get a list of the items that all the users have checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a middle table that foreign keys to both tables.

Eg `user_items -> useritems_id (PK), user_id (FK), item_id (FK)`

Answer (score 0):

comma separated fields are a PITA to search.. better make a third table: (userid, itemid)